# Change the avatar of group in buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am struggling to change the buddypress group avatar but cannot able to change it. I searched a lot on google but only find to customize the size of buddypress group avatart or find some code to change the default group avatar. So any body can tell me that how can I change the buddypress group avatar. Actually what I need a PHP script that can able to change the buddypress group avatar by using some hooks etc. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

follow this article it will help you to change default avatar in BuddyPress

https://buddypress.org/support/topic/changing-the-default-mystery-man-avatar/

https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/add-new-default-avatar.1.3.1.zip

download plugin and install it

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i want to change every group avatar.I don't want to do this by using the buddypress group avatar uploading functionality.I want to make my own script to upload group avatar.What procedure should i follow?